# "it would be nice to make the certificate check/checked"

Tags: causatives

I am sometimes confused on using causitive forms..Should I use causitive form in this sentence?

> 1.I thought it would be nice to make the certificate check in order to make sure it is genuine.
>
> 2.I thought it would be nice to make the certificate checked in order to make sure it is genuine.

So I will ask a instutition to check.

---

Generally the rule I follow is that if there is a object, then I  use causitive form.
For example:

> I had my hair cut.
>
> I made my car repaired.

But if there is someone then:

> The teacher made the students mob the floor.
>
> My dad makes me do my homework before going to bed every day.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with people as objects it does work differently. You can use either "make" or "had" in those sentences above, with the teacher and the dad. Just differs in strength.

For the certificate, these would both be right:

> I thought it would be nice to HAVE the certificate checked in order to make sure it is genuine.
>
> I thought it would be nice to MAKE the agency check the certificate in order to make sure it is genuine.

However, "make" suggests a command or force and may sound too strong here. It's OK for teachers, parents, and such but not so good for workplaces. I can "make" my computer program check the certificate, but I would "have" the institution or person check it, or "ask" them to.

> I thought it would be nice to have the boss check the certificate in order to make sure it is genuine.
>
> I thought it would be nice to ask the boss to check the certificate in order to make sure it is genuine.

I wouldn't say

> I made my car repaired.

But

> I had my car repaired. (someone else did it for me)
>
> I repaired my car. (I did it myself)

Comment: Thank you for very good answer.But can I ask a few questions more since you pointed out some meaning differences between them 1) how about using of " get" in causitive sentences in this sense? Is it more like make or have ? and where should I use it ?  2) Can I say "...have the certificate checked to the agency in order to..." 3) " the teacher made her house cleaned to her students " (by forcing sense )  ..and if I say "I made my car repaired." does it sound like repairmen are too busy but I push them so much to get priority  or I do it by threating them like using a gun ?

Comment: @Murat- To force them into repairing your car you would say, "I made ***them*** repair my car."   Also, OP's original #1 sentence (*1.I thought it would be nice to make the certificate check in order to make sure it is genuine.*) is a valid sentence but it turns *check* into a noun modified by an adjective *certificate*.  I might say this if I were writing some code and decided to add make my code perform a validity check on the certificate. (In other words, *I thought it would be nice to have my program make/perform the certificate check ...*)

Answer (score 1):

> I thought it would be nice to make a certificate check in order to make sure it is genuine.

Here you are using "certificate check" as a noun phrase instead of "examination".